# Alamofire: [Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

The service I'm connecting to is using a self signed certificate. 
For dev purposes I do not want to validate that chain.

Using swift 3 with Alamofire 4. 
Fixed the ATS accordingly:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>url.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Code to connect and disable evaluation.

```
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "example.domain.com": .pinCertificates(
            certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
            validateCertificateChain: false,
            validateHost: true
        ),
        "sub.url.com": .disableEvaluation
    ]

    let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )

    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic /*...*/"]

    sessionManager.request("https://sub.url.com/path", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        debugPrint(response)

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
    }
```

Error log from dumpPrint

> [Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://sub.url.com/path,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, 
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://sub.url.com/path}

URL has been masked.

Answer (score 13):

To retain `SessionManager` instance you need to capture it in closure passed to `responseJSON`:

```
sessionManager.request("https://sub.url.com/path", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    let _ = sessionManager // retain
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise `sessionManager` is deallocated shortly it goes out of scope and any executing requests are cancelled.

Comment: This is not a proper solution and is an anti-pattern. You should make your manager instance a singleton, or use some other way of persisting it beyond local usage.

Comment: @JonShier It's not so widely used solution to be an anti-pattern :) You can run into situation when you do not need to keep `SessionManager` during the whole lifetime of an application, so it's wise to deallocate it after request is completed.

Comment: Then the lifetime should be properly extended, perhaps by storing the manager somewhere and properly canceling it out when the time comes. Forcing a local reference just to keep something alive is always an anti-pattern, as it means you're not properly handling the lifetimes of your variables.

Comment: @JonShier I agree with you. The above "workaround" is usually used to retain some instance defined in method scope after method returns. We can define `var sessionManager: SessionManager?` variable at class scope and set it to `nil` in `responseJSON`. This is cleaner solution but how does it differ from the "workaround" in terms of memory management and other underlying things?

Answer (score 8):

Please add this statement to the end of responseJson block:

```
manager.session.invalidateAndCancel()
```

It happens if the object of the manager is not retained till execution of the block completes, so this would ensure its retention.

Cheers!

Comment: sessionManager.request("https://sub.url.com/path", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            /*...*/
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
            
            sessionManager.session.invalidateAndCancel()
        }

Comment: sorry about that, I screwed up my config when I tried.

Answer (score 4):

```
self.getSessionManager().request(urlstring, method: methods, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: Header).responseJSON(queue: nil, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) { (responseObject) in ... .... }.session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
```

Just put the method of invalidate after task finish, means `session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()`

Answer (score 2):

Please  check in `sessiondidReceiveChallenge:` delegate implementation of `NSURLSession`. Chances are `NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge` is getting executed somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly manage the lifetime of your `SessionManager` instance. Most commonly this is done by making a singleton instance. Otherwise, when your manager goes out of scope and is `deinit`ed, all outstanding requests will be cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of reason to why your requests "cancelled".
In your case your request cancels immediately.
You can refer to this issue in [Alamofire repository issues](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1684)

> **jshier** commented on Oct 10, 2016
>
> An unexpected error -999 almost always means your SessionManager was
> deallocated, cancelling any ongoing requests. I suggest you create a
> singleton value for your custom SessionManager, or perhaps just
> reevaluate if you really need one.

if you create a singleton value for your object it remains in memory and prevent from deallocate

and another thing that i avoid is to name your variables diffrent, a sessionManager is in Alamofire and your variable is also called sessionManager.

### Alamofire 4.7 , Swift 4

```
import Alamofire

class Networking {

  public static let sharedManager: SessionManager = {
      let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
      configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest=20
      let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration, delegate: SessionManager.default.delegate)
      return manager
  }()
}
```

### Alamofire 5.4.4 , Siwft 5.2

```
import Alamofire

class Networking {

  static let APIManager: Session = {
      let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
      configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
      let delegate = Session.default.delegate
      let manager = Session.init(configuration: configuration,
                                 delegate: delegate,
                                 startRequestsImmediately: true,
                                 cachedResponseHandler: nil)
      return manager
  }()
}
```