# certificate pinning in alamofire is wrog

Tags: swift, alamofire, certificate-pinning

I want to use certificate pinning in `Alamofire` .
here is my code :

```
            // Set up certificates
            let pathToCert = Bundle.main.path(forResource: cert, ofType: "der")
            let localCertificate = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToCert!)
            let certificates = [SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate!)!]

            // Configure the trust policy manager
            let serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
                validateCertificateChain: false,
                validateHost: true)

            let serverTrustPolicies = ["hostname": serverTrustPolicy]
            let serverTrustPolicyManager = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)

            let sessionManager = SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,serverTrustPolicyManager: serverTrustPolicyManager)


            sessionManager
                .request()...
```

this is my info.plist ->

[image: infoplist]

and I get this error : 
`load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"`

I searched a lot but I couldn't find any thing to solve my problem . 
I convert my `.crt` file to `.der` file using `open ssl` .

Comment: I get a similar ‘error’ code -999 when using Mapbox API to download map tiles. For me it just means that sometimes the API will cancel some of the requests it has made. It looks like an error but really it is just an operation, that is no longer needed, that has been cancelled automatically. Does your code run okay?

Comment: @Magnas how can I test it ? It seams to be okay

Comment: This question has some suggestions for how to retain the `sessionManager` that may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984880/alamofire-result-failure-error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-999-cancelled

Comment: thank you , problem was that session manager deallocated  @Magnas

Answer (score 0):

In addition to seeing this error when the `SessionManager` is deinit'd before the request completes, as was the issue here, it also what you'll see when certificate pinning fails in Alamofire 4. Updating to Alamofire 5 will give you a much better error in both cases.